# Effect of enabling IKEv2 VPN in azure point-to-site configuration

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, azure

I need to connect a few macbooks to our existing Azure VPN. According [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert#installmac) I need to enable IKEv2.

Are there any risks with this? If I enable it will the existing VPN connections be continue to work?

Comment: IKEv2 is just a protocol for VPN. I think it doesn't cause risks if you use the VPN in a right way. For you Network, you can choose connect only one VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling IKEv2 required all machines to reinstall the VPN client.